# Calling an async api from a xamarin application

Tags: xamarin, web, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, webapi

I am working on a xamarin mobile application, upon making an async call to the exposed api, i do not get any error, however when i execute the .Result on the task the call never proceeds and it stuck forever.

[Click here to see stringResourceResponse details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb4RH.png)
The same .Result call from a separate project (windows service) in the same solution works.

Any idea if .NET standard is causing limitation in executing async tasks, any advice would be helpful, thanks

Code added below:

```
//This is code from app.xaml.cs

var stringResourceApi = new StringResourceApiTask();
Task.Run(() =>
{
    a = controller.CallStringResourceApi(stringResourceApi);
}).Wait();
```

```
public class MobileController
    {
        public string CallStringResourceApi(StringResourceApiTask stringResourceApiTask)
        {
            return stringResourceApiTask.Start(StringResourceUrl);
        }
    }
```

```
public override string Start(string URL)
{
    var stringResourceResponse = SendRequest(url, "", HttpMethod.Get);
    var result = stringResourceResponse.Result;
    return result;
}
```

```
protected async Task < string > SendRequest(string url, string uri, HttpMethod method, int attempt = 1, int maxAttempts = 5)
{
    return await SendRequest(
        url, uri, Key, Secret, method, string.Empty, attempt, maxAttempts)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

```
protected async Task<string> SendRequest(string url, string uri, string key, string secret, HttpMethod method,
            string requestBody = "", int attempt = 1, int maxAttempts = 5)
        {
            if (attempt > maxAttempts)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var client = InitialiseHttpClient(key, secret);

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                RequestUri = string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) ? new Uri(uri) : new Uri(url),
                Method = method,
            };

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestBody))
            {
                request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            }

            SetOutputText($"Attempting to communicate with {uri}...{Environment.NewLine}");

            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                using (var content = response.Content)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();                       
                    }
                    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                    {
                        
                        if (attempt > maxAttempts)
                        {
                            SetOutputText(errorMessage);
                        }

                        return await SendRequest(url, uri, key, secret, method, requestBody, attempt + 1).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }

                    var responseBody = await content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    var isSuccessResponseButEmptyBody = response.IsSuccessStatusCode &&
                                                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseBody) ||
                                                         string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responseBody));
                    if (!isSuccessResponseButEmptyBody)
                    {
                        return responseBody;
                    }

                    
                    if (attempt > maxAttempts)
                    {
                        SetOutputText(errorMessage);
                    }

                    return await SendRequest(url, uri, key, secret, method, requestBody, attempt + 1).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Some code, please.

Comment: The web api which is being called in the Url has hmac (hashed based authentication) , not sure if this is not being generated i.e key etc at the xamarin end ?. I mean does xamarin have a limitation in supporting hmac based authenticated api's etc ?

Comment: please do not shove a bunch of unformatted code into a comment.  I'd suggest you delete this post, then create a new one with the relevant code, properly formatted, included as well as other useful information

Comment: Pls refer to updated post with code, thanks

Comment: have you verified that your url is reachable from your device or emulator?  And it's not at all clear how the code you posted fits together - the key method seems to be `CallStringResourceApi` but that method is not shown.

Comment: Do we need to add a specific nuget package which allows xamarin for aync await calls to start executing, ?. Its interesting that same code is executed with results obtained from the api when done from a windows service project

Comment: @ActiveDEV Do not use `.Result`, use `await`, you are hanging the thread

Answer (score 1):

> when i execute the .Result on the task the call never proceeds and it stuck forever.

Yes. This is a [common deadlock situation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). When code running on the UI thread blocks on asynchronous code, a deadlock usually occurs.

> The same .Result call from a separate project (windows service) in the same solution works.

It works because the Win32 service code does not run on a UI thread.

The proper solution is to remove the blocking code; use `await` instead. This in turn will cause the calling methods to become `async` (e.g., `StringResourceApiTask.Start`), and they should also be `await`ed, etc. The usage of `async` and `await` should "grow" through your code; this is natural.

Alternatively, you can block in a thread pool thread, e.g., `Task.Run(() => a = controller.CallStringResourceApi(stringResourceApi)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`. This is a bit of a hack (consuming an unnecessary thread), but it's a quick way to remove the deadlock. Note that this hack is **not** appropriate for ASP.NET apps; it's acceptable here since this is a UI app.